# Adding tftopl/pltotf to TeXlive basic

Tags: texlive

I started from a basic TeXlive 2014 installation on Mac.

Recently I came across the need for the tftopl and pltotf programs.
As far as I can tell, they should be provided by the `texware` package.
Its package description reads

> Basic utitility programs, comprising: - dvitype, which converts a TeX output (DVI) file to a plain text file (see also the DVI Text Language suite); - pooltype, which converts a TeX-suite program's "pool" (string) file into human-readable form; and - tftopl and pltotf, which convert TeX Font Metric (TFM) file to human readable Property List (PL) files and vice versa.

After successfully installing the `texware` package using `tlmgr`, the tftopl and pltotf programs are nowhere to be found.
This is confirmed by `tlmgr info texware --list`:

```
package:     texware
category:    TLCore
shortdesc:   Utility programs for use with TeX.
longdesc:    ...
installed:   Yes
revision:    33736
sizes:       bin: 437k
relocatable: No
cat-date:    2014-02-26 23:03:13 +0100
cat-license: knuth
collection:  collection-binextra
Included files, by type:
depending package texware.universal-darwin:
bin files (all platforms):
 bin/universal-darwin/dvitype
 bin/universal-darwin/pooltype
depending package texware.x86_64-darwin:
bin files (all platforms):
 bin/x86_64-darwin/dvitype
 bin/x86_64-darwin/pooltype
```

So it seems that tftopl/pltotf are no longer part of the `texware` package.
I have checked that they are not present in the archive, so it is not a faulty installation on my system.

How can these programs be added to a basic installation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are in `fontware`, part of `collection-fontutils`

```
> tlmgr info fontware --list
package:     fontware
category:    TLCore
installed:   Yes
revision:    33736
sizes:       doc: 49k, bin: 1149k
relocatable: No
collection:  collection-fontutils
Included files, by type:
doc files:
  texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/pltotf.1
  texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/pltotf.man1.pdf
  texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/tftopl.1
  texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/tftopl.man1.pdf
  texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/vftovp.1
  texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/vftovp.man1.pdf
  texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/vptovf.1
  texmf-dist/doc/man/man1/vptovf.man1.pdf
depending package fontware.universal-darwin:
bin files (all platforms):
 bin/universal-darwin/pltotf
 bin/universal-darwin/tftopl
 bin/universal-darwin/vftovp
 bin/universal-darwin/vptovf
depending package fontware.x86_64-darwin:
bin files (all platforms):
 bin/x86_64-darwin/pltotf
 bin/x86_64-darwin/tftopl
 bin/x86_64-darwin/vftovp
 bin/x86_64-darwin/vptovf
```

The *depending packages* are automatically installed based on the host system, so there should be no need to install them manually.

Comment: Did I miss something, or is this really not obvious?

Comment: @Nicolas No, it isn't obvious; the two programs are among `texware` in Knuth's distribution, but his division is historical: for instance `vftovp` and `vptovf` are in `etc`.